# If $M\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ has $\dim(M)<n$, is $\Bbb R^n-M$ dense in $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth properly embedded (closed) submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ and suppose that
$$\dim(M)<n.$$
Is it necessarily true that $\Bbb R^n-M$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$?

Intuitively, it seems obviously true to me, but I cannot find a way to prove it.

Comment: Yes. You only have to prove that points of $M$ are limit points of sequences living outside of $M$. If $M = \mathbb R^d \varsubsetneq \mathbb R^n$, that's easy: $(x,0) = \lim (x,1/n)$. The general case reduces to this one through a coordinate chart.

Comment: @PseudoNeo Thanks, I understand that argument.